# How to deploy assignement of Compact layout & Record Lightning page to Record Type/Profil

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, vs-code, package.xml, deployment-error

How can i deploy assignement of Compact layout & Record Lightning page to Record Type/Profil .
I tried this package ,the compact layout and record page were deployed properly but the assignement to profil and record type were not deployed ,what i need to add in my package to deploy assignements  also ?

```
    <types>
        <members>Account.CFCompactLayout</members>
        <name>CompactLayout</name>
    </types>
    
    <types>
        <members>Comptes_de_Facturation</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
```

Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

You need to include the metadata that is actually changed by your action: in your case, this is the **custom object** for the compact layout assignments and all of the **custom application(s)** included in the Lighting Page Assignments. Based on what I see in the screenshots, the below should reflect what you changed:

```
<types>
    <members>Account.CFCompactLayout</members>
    <name>CompactLayout</name>
</types>
    
<types>
    <members>Comptes_de_Facturation</members>
    <name>FlexiPage</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>Console_de_Vente</members>
    <name>CustomApplication</name>
</types>
```

---

*Details*

You're asking two things

**Compact Layout Assignments**

This is stored in the [custom object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) metadata under `compactLayoutAssignment` within the `RecordType` property so you need to include whatever object you're changing the record type/compact layout assignment. It'll look like something like this within the metadata you pull

```
recordTypes xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <fullName>YourRecordTypeName</fullName>
  <active>true</active>
  <compactLayoutAssignment>YourCompactLayout</compactLayoutAssignment>
....
```

**Lightning Page Assignment**

This is stored in two different locations depending on what you do.

*Org Default* - Setting a page as the org default changes the custom object metadata under `actionOverrides`. You'll see something like this within your object metadata:

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <comment>Action override updated by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
    <content>Your_Lightning_Page</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
  </actionOverrides>
```

*Assignment by app, profile, and record type* or *App Default* - This is stored in the [custom application](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm) metadata. It'll be under the `profileActionOverrides` field and look something like this:

```
 <profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <content>Your_Lightning_Page</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>Account</pageOrSobjectType>
    <recordType>Account.YourRecordType</recordType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>Admin</profile>
  </profileActionOverrides>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ,very good explanation

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the profiles when retrieving/deploying:

```
<types>
    <members>Account.CFCompactLayout</members>
    <name>CompactLayout</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>Comptes_de_Facturation</members>
    <name>FlexiPage</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Thank you .So i need only profiles in my package but how about assignement to record type ?

Comment: @user3499987 the mdapi will retrieve the related mappings if you retrieve the profile and the things you want permissions/assignments for. That's how it works.

Comment: It may work, but let's be be aware about doing this, because deploying * regarding profiles you will replace everything, in terms of profile, in the target ORG